# F# Public Override of Protected Methods

Tags: f#

I've just started learning F# and I'm using it with Monogame to create a simple game to help myself learn the various features of the language. I've hit a roadblock trying to access my game class from outside because the Monogame Game class defines the methods as protected. Trying to do a public override of the method throws an error, telling me setting an accessibility modifiers are not permitted.

---

**Base Class Defined in C#**

```
public class Base
{
    protected virtual void Method()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

---

**Public Override in F#**

```
type Game as game = 
    inherit Base()

    //Error: Accessibility modifiers are not permitted on overrides or interface implementations
    override public game.Method = 
        //...
        ()
```

---

**Q: What is the correct way to do a public F# override of an inherited protected C# method?**

---

Comment: I don't think you can do that in C# either; at least, when I attempt to do this with C# with the `Base` and `Game` classes, it doesn't compile, giving this error message: "cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member"

Comment: Just create another method in Game class which will be public and will call the protected method, i.e. `member game.PubMethod() = base.Method()`

Comment: @MarkSeemann: You are correct. The Visual Studio IDE for C# doesn't warn users with a red squiggly like it does for F#, until after a compilation attempt.

Comment: @Endrju: Thanks, that's most likely what I will end up doing.

Comment: just as a side note: the self-identifier `game` in `type Game as game` is almost never needed and can be an indicator for a possible *smell* (here it is surely not needed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing accessibility on overrides is not allowed, in either F# or C#. Based on @Endjru's, the best approach is to use a wrapper method that is public to call the protected method;

```
type Game as game = 
    inherit Base()

    override game.Method = 
        //...
        ()

    member game.PublicMethod = game.Method
```