# Overriding a .NET protected member in F# produces a public member

Tags: c#, f#, overriding, blazor-webassembly, protected

I have encountered a seemingly "weird" situation. Repro:

1. Create an F# library
2. Add a component class type, inheriting ComponentBase
3. Override BuildRenderTree

```
//Comp1Base.fs
namespace ClassLibrary1

open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components

type Comp1Base() = 
    inherit ComponentBase()

    override __.BuildRenderTree(builder) = base.BuildRenderTree(builder)
```

4. Create a Blazor WASM project (C#) and reference the F# project
5. Add a razor component to this project and inherit from the F# base component

```
//Comp1.razor
@inherits ClassLibrary1.Comp1Base
```

Now the Blazor project doesn't compile:

```
Error   CS0507  'Comp1.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'Comp1Base.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder)' BlazorApp1  C:\Temp\qwerty\BlazorApp1\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Comp1_razor.g.cs   85  N/A
```

ILSpy shows that the overridden member in F# is public, while the base member is protected:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: In F# the default is public, unlike C# which is private. You have to specify visibility protected.

Comment: The `protected` modifier doesn't exist in F#. I suppose making an overridden member `public` was seen as the appropriate compiler behaviour https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390515/why-isnt-there-a-protected-access-modifier-in-f

Comment: Does this answer your question? [F# Public Override of Protected Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625830/f-public-override-of-protected-methods)

Comment: @user1344783 F# doesn't have protected visibility

Comment: @tranquillity I think there shouldn't be cases where F# cannot replicate what C# can do

Comment: @BrianBerns No it doesn't. BuildRenderTree is called by  Blazor (the framework), not from the app code. Blazor generates code from razor that contains a protected override to BuildRenderTree exact name. The F# public override breaks this pattern.

Comment: There is a separate framework https://fsbolero.io/ to use F# with Blazor. I've not used it but I would guess they have built in the necessary workarounds for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you cannot do this in F# directly.
You could write a more F#-friendly wrapper type in C# like so (untested code, for illustration purposes):

```cs
public class FSharpFriendlyComponentBase: ComponentBase
{
    readonly Action<RenderTreeBuilder> _buildRenderTree

    public FSharpFriendlyComponentBase(Action<RenderTreeBuilder> buildRenderTree) =>
        _buildRenderTree = buildRenderTree;

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
        _buildRenderTree(builder);
    }
}
```

This would then allow you to implement the required behavior in F#:

```ml
let myComponentBase = 
    FSharpFriendlyComponentBase(fun builder -> 
        ... your behavior here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late but I hope it helps:

**In C# (I'm talking about C#) you can't change the *access modifier* when overriding a method as [Microsoft Docs says.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0507)**